# How to connect to mongodb via unix socket in python

Tags: python, mongodb

Is there any way to connect to mongodb via unix socket in python, while the official **pymongo** module does not support unix socket yet.

I'd like any third-party alternatives, or patches, while I've searched around and did not find one.

I do not like an ORM-style library since the mongodb => python dicts are natural and easy to use, so I did not take something like MongoEngine into account.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

MongoDB, by default, creates a unix socket at `/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock`. As of pymongo 2.4 you can make a connection like this:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
CONNECTION = MongoClient('/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock')
```

Additionally you can disable this behavior by starting mongod with `--nounixsocket` or specify an alternate location with `--unixSocketPrefix <path>`

MongoDB will always create and listen on a UNIX socket, unless `--nounixsocket` is set, `--bind_ip` is not set, or `--bind_ip` specifies `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: So this was finally implemented since pymongo 2.4. Thank you!

Comment: Say, "as of pymongo 2.4". Is pymongo the one creating the unix socket? Or is it "`...sock`. As of pymongo 2.4, you can make a connection..."

Answer (score 7):

Update for MongoDB v3.x

If you upgrade to MongoDB 3.x on linux, the group and other permissions on /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock have been removed.  You will receive permission denied error's when you connect using MongoClient(host='/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock')

To fix this, upgrade your MongoDB configuration file to YAML format, which includes the filePermissions option so you set the permissions back.

Example /etc/mongod.conf in YAML format:

```
storage:
    dbPath: "/var/lib/mongodb"
systemLog:
    destination: file
    path: "/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log"
    logAppend: true
net:
    unixDomainSocket:
        filePermissions: 0777
```

Answer (score 1):

Outside the scope of Python, you can build a proxy between TCP/IP socket and unix domain socket. So that, you can still use pymongo

Either [netcat](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nc) or [socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/) can do this.

```
nc -l 1234 | nc -U /tmp/foo
```

or

```
socat TCP-LISTEN:1234,reuseaddr,fork UNIX-CLIENT:/tmp/foo
```

See also:

[Redirecting TCP-traffic to a UNIX domain socket under Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2149564/redirecting-tcp-traffic-to-a-unix-domain-socket-under-linux)

Comment: Thank you anyway, but this is not exactly what I want :) I want to use unix socket for performance and stability, but if I build a proxy in TCP and forwards queries the two goals are all missing.