# Working with mongodb without a live port (embedded)

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am starting mongodb from C# code.
I am connecting to it without mentioning any port:

```
ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();     
start.FileName = dir + @"\mongod.exe";
start.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
start.UseShellExecute = false;

start.Arguments = "--dbpath d:\test\mongodb\data";

Process mongod = Process.Start(start);


MongoClient client = new MongoClient();
MongoServer server = client.GetServer();
MongoDatabase database = server.GetDatabase("db_name");
```

at the mongodb console (output window) I see that mongodb  is listening to a  port.
Is it possible to start mongo without a port?

Comment: http://fir3pho3nixx.blogspot.com/2011/08/using-mongodb-as-embedded-application.html

Comment: What good would MongoDB be without a port? Nothing could communicate with it. It has a default port.

Comment: @ShahroozJefriㇱ - not sure why you linked to that? MongoDB still needs a port.

Comment: @WiredPrairie - I want it embedded, no one will access it from out side the app i am writing

Answer (score 2):

You can't. MongoDB is a standalone server. The only way to communicate with MongoDB is using TCP [or unix sockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8411032/how-to-connect-to-mongodb-via-unix-socket-in-python), so it's never a truly embedded database. Auto-Deploying the database doesn't make it an embedded database, it will have its own process and it will be available to other applications.

When you don't configure a port, MongoDB (and it's drivers) will use port 27017.

If you need an embedded database, use one. [Candidates for C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639846/what-is-a-good-embedded-database-to-use-with-c) include SQLite, db4o, [perst](http://www.mcobject.com/perst) and it's BSD-licensed fork [volante](https://github.com/kjk/volante), and a ton of smaller projects like [siaqodb](http://siaqodb.com/) (some of these not free).

MongoDB will be trouble because it's rather aggressive about memory allocation and might need repair when things go wrong.

Comment: Also, depending on the nature of your application, even if it were technically possible, the license may cause you trouble as it's AGPL.

Comment: @WiredPrairie - thanks, so working with(!) port allows me to use it commercially and free of limitations? thanks

Comment: @Shazam - I'm not an attorney and don't want to give legal advice. Bundling MongoDB may trigger the GPL, requiring you to release your source as well. Consult an attorney, or use an embeddable DB as suggested in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't start `mongod` without it [listening to a port](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/default-mongodb-port/), however to restrict access you can:

- use the [`bind_ip`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#bind_ip) configuration option to limit connections to localhost only (127.0.0.1)
- use the [`port`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#port) configuration option to change to a non-standard port specific to your application
- [configure authentication](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/security-access-control/) and appropriate user roles

Given you are planning to spawn the `mongod` process on the user's machine, you unfortunately can't prevent determined users with Administrator access from bypassing any of the above restrictions.

As noted in the answer by @mnemosyn, there are certainly databases such as SQLite that are [designed to be embeddable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_database) and compiled into your application code without spawning external processes.